# Переход на новую страницу для текстовой игры Android

Tags: java, android, разработка-игр

Пытаюсь сделать простенькую текстовую игру на андроид. При нажатии любой кнопки экран должен сменяться на новый `activity` (как я думал), где будет выбор других кнопок и текст. Но сделав приложение с  `Intent` при нажатии на кнопку открывается новое окно и при нажатии на кнопку Назад возвращается на ту же страницу.
Так вот вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на любую кнопку новое `activity` стало как бы главным?

Answer (score 0):

В старой активити пропиши после запуска новой `finish();`

Также советую сделать смену содержимого нужных тебе контейнеров (кнопки/текст) заместо создания новой активити.

Comment: А если мне потребуется 3 копки, вместо 4, какая есть команда чтобы ее скрыть или удалить?